# C# Web Service and XML / Cannot Implicitly convert type int

Tags: c#, web-services, type-conversion

I have a web service called `test_WebService`. In that web service I have the following reference:

```
public enum getAttributeData : int
{
  [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
  DataFile = 0,

  [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
  DataType = 1,

  [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
  DataSource = 2,
}
```

The following method is in the web service:

```
GetDataFromService(getAttributeData *entity*)
```

I have the following code:

```
client_Service newSevice = new client_Service();

getAttributeData AD = 2;

String result = GetDataFromService(AD);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

I am getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type int to 'getAttributeData;. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must cast your enum:

```
getAttributeData AD = (getAttributeData) 2;
```